# How to get text from span html python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to get the text between two spans with selenium

```
<div style="display:inline">
    <span style="margin-right:4px">£</span>
    <input type="text" name="binPrice" id="binPrice" aria-describedby="err_binPrice" value="8.95" md="dt|DOUBLE||em|Please enter a Buy it now price.||vm|Please enter a valid Buy it now price." vld="1" maxlength="10" aria-required="true">
</div>
```

python

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@style="margin-right:4px"]\span')
```

I would like to get the "£"

Comment: When writing code use backticks i.e. ` e.g. `<div></div>`

Comment: I am a newbee in this site. Yes i know but when i input code on html it blends within. So now i added a "." so it differs

Comment: @JimMede please share more html code, I think you can't use locator just with : `<span style="margin -right:4px">£</span>`

Comment: <div style="display:inline"><span style="margin-right:4px">£</span><input type="text" name="binPrice" id="binPrice" aria-describedby="err_binPrice" value="8.95" md="dt|DOUBLE||em|Please enter a Buy it now price.||vm|Please enter a valid Buy it now price." vld="1" maxlength="10" aria-required="true"></div>

Comment: @frianH this part is enough i think

Comment: @JimMede sure in your web page only have one element with attribute `style="margin-right:4px` ?

Comment: I added an answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: Instead of adding the HTML to comments, edit your question and add all important information there. That way future readers don't have to read all comments to get all the info they need to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing according to your latest comment.
First, your xpath is wrong. You have an unnecessary '\span' in the xpath.
Try with:

```
xpath = '//span[@style="margin-right:4px"]'
```

Second, I note that using style attribute is not a good idea because there might be several elements with the same style. I recommend using the input element because it has an ID. 
So it would be like:

```
xpath = "//input[@id='binPrice']/../span"
```

This would be more robust.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i removed unnecessary '\span' in the xpath and it works. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear that. My pleasure.